# VS2017: The debugger is not properly installed. Cannot debug the requested type of code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise edition and when I am running my application getting the below error.

[image: Error]

Comment: Its interesting to see that I am getting this error only when I am running a Web API project.

Answer (score 40):

Turning off Silverlight debugging solved the problem for me.

Go to the web application's *Properties*, right click on the web project and select properties. On the *Web* tab, turn off Silverlight.

[image: Turn off Silverlight debugging]

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. This is still a problem today with VS 2022. I unchecked the box and it fixed the issue. 1000 Thumbs up.

Comment: This solved my problem too on Visual Studio 2022. Just wanted to add the Information to right click on your web project and then click on Properties to reach the settings.

Answer (score 13):

For me the fix was found in that thread, I disabled javascript debugging in the Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Javascript debugging...

Seems that it was having issues debugging in chrome..

[direct link to the answer](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/answers/38361/view.html)

Comment: The link no longer works. This [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26630/the-debugger-is-not-properly-installed-cannot-debu.html) has a discussion of the main solutions mentioned here.

Answer (score 13):

I solved this problem for Visual Studio 2017 Community.

Clean folders:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug

Then recover Visual Studio

P.S. This issue happen because dlls corrupted. 
[Here is this case](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yash/2007/09/20/debugger-not-working/)

Comment: what do you mean by recover?

Comment: I think by recover he means run the repair from the persistent installer. It's listed under the small hamburger menu. This worked for me after I deleted the directories mentioned.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Before this, I tried reinstalling all the MS components. Clean the registry by CCleaner. Failed.

Comment: It would be useful if you explained what "clean" and "recover" means, and how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known issue and is under investigation by the VS 2017 team. More information here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26630/the-debugger-is-not-properly-installed-cannot-debu.html

Answer (score 2):

For me the following solved the problem:
In Visual Studio 2017, open the property page for the web project. Go to tab "Web". Select Start Action "Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this issue after installing .NET Core SDK 2.0 without removing old .NET Core SDK's. It seems that having both causes issues.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting a different browser (next to the green Run triangle).  There is more info at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26630/the-debugger-is-not-properly-installed-cannot-debu.html, as noted by dajo.

Answer (score 1):

Install Visual Studio 2015 Professional.

I really wish this was not the answer, but it was the only way I got around the `debugger not installed` problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual studo 2022, you might have enabled the JavaScript debugging. Please uncheck that, it works.

Go to TOOLS->Options->Debugging->General and uncheck it as below picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after uninstalling some Microsoft SDK's, (I had 0kb space on my PC so started deleting random stuff from the control panel, and thought I only had these SDK's installed from previous projects, whoops!)

I had 1 forum say to install the "Windows Communication Foundation" module which I did through the "Visual Studio Installer" app, but that didn't fix it.

I then did a full repair of Visual Studio, also "checked for windows updates" because a lot of the SDK's must have come from Windows updates over the years.

How I fixed the issue (check if issue is resolved after each step):

- Windows updates (To get the SDK's if you deleted them by accident like me!)
- Run Visual Studio Installer  from start menu > Repair and carry out updates afterwards if necessary)
- Try the Windows Communication Foundation fix that is explained here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-the-debugger-is-not-properly-installed-run-s/53705