# Error after installing Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Visual studio 2017 community edition installs fine with no error messages on my 64-bit windows 7 desktop.

I am able to start a new project for example a new windows forms c# project.

However when pressing the start button as pictured below the following error message appears, I have tried to repair and uninstall and reinstall visual studio however that has not changed anything.

I am able to run (and therefore compile successfully) by pressing ctrl+f5.

Is there anything else I can try, and is there a link to a previous stable version of visual studio as an alternative please?

For reference this problem has occured and been reported here: 
[Visual studio 2015 debugger "not installed properly" & "process cannot acces file - file in use" build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051463/visual-studio-2015-debugger-not-installed-properly-process-cannot-acces-fil)   (I also tried the fix here but this did not work either)
Here too: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26630/the-debugger-is-not-properly-installed-cannot-debu.html (this seems to be the latest issue log)

[VS2017: The debugger is not properly installed. Cannot debug the requested type of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943239/vs2017-the-debugger-is-not-properly-installed-cannot-debug-the-requested-type)

[image: button]
[image: Error Message]

There appears to be a fix here but I'm not sure how to piece together what downloads I need, from the answer here it looks like there is some component required from VS2015 to allow VS2017 to work: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a75214be-4720-4134-aca8-f26751ea18a1/community-vs-2017-on-windows10-64-bit-debugger-is-not-properly-installed?forum=vsdebug

Update: I managed to install visual studio express 2015 and that works fine, although it didn't fix the current issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing a more beefy version of Visual Studio 2015, such as Visual Studio 2015 Professional. That is what worked for me.

This is definitely a bug with the installation process of Visual Studio 2017 on systems that have not previously had Visual Studio installed on them.