# After upgrading from VS2015 to VS2017: The Debugger is not properly installed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I've been working on a C# MVC application in VS2015 with no problems. Recently I've upgraded to VS2017. I opened the same project in VS2017, but whenever I try to run it, I get the exact same error verbatim as described in

this question [VS2017: The debugger is not properly installed. Cannot debug the requested type of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943239/vs2017-the-debugger-is-not-properly-installed-cannot-debug-the-requested-type)

I've followed every single piece of advice in that thread. I've also performed a repair on my installation - but none of the suggestions worked for me.

It's August now, so I wonder if anything has changed and if there is a solution now.

I have a feeling the problem is probably due to the differences between VS2015 and VS2017 - this was originally something built in VS2015 after all.

Comment: Did you try to start with a different browser (not Chrome, that is)

Comment: Yep, I've tried that.

Answer (score 0):

I also had issues few months ago when i upgraded VS2015 to VS2017 and one of my big project that i was running on visual studio 2015 stopped working. That project had seveleral class libraries and DLLs added. VS2017 asked me to installed required libraries/ddl one by one, which i did and still didn't work.

So what I did was, Uninstalled the upgraded version of visual studio 2017 and re-installed the complete visual studio 2017 from MSDN website (selecting the default selection of features). And then i loaded my Project in VS2017 fresh copy and it worked.

I suggest you to try the same